# Value of GPIO in a slider buttton changing without doing anything

Tags: gpio

I want to use a slider button of 3 pins.

Actually I'm using 2 of it, like the schematic below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmGjYb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My code is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
green_led = 21
GPIO.setup(green_led, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    green_led_state = GPIO.input(green_led)
    print('#### - ',green_led_state, ' - ####')
```

In my opinion whith this code, if don't touch my slider always have to print the same value (1 or 0) depending of its position. And if I change the position of the slider, print the other value all the time.

But now, without touching nothing is printing 0 and 1 randomly (I think randomly). Why this? Why some times has current and sometimes not?

Thanks

Comment: Like your earlier question, you are connecting LEDs without a current limiting resistor. You are lucky not to have blown something up, but excessive current will eventually cause problems.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put in the schematic but it is in my real circuit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GPIO set as an input will float (read randomly low/high) until a voltage is applied.

The simplest thing to do is set the internal resistor pulls to the opposite of the value set by the switch.
If I read your circuit correctly use

`GPIO.setup(green_led, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)`